# Validated variable null warning

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations, compiler-warnings

In Eclipse (4.7.2) with `null analysis -> potential null access` set to give me a warning.

Given the following code:

```
public class Test {

    // validator method
    static boolean hasText(String s) {
        return !(s == null || s.trim().isEmpty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // s could come from anywhere and is null iff the data does not exist
        String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : null;
        if (hasText(s)) {
            // Potential null pointer access: The variable s may be null at this location
            System.out.println(s.length());
            // ... do actual stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

how can I avoid the potential null warning? `@NotNull` won't work since `null` is a valid input and the output is a `boolean`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that if this validation method returns true then the validated value was non-null?

Is there some better way to handle validation methods like this?

Thanks.

---

Update for clarity:

The data comes from user input (from xml or .properties file) and will be null iff the data does exist.

Never producing `null` (eg. setting it to `""`) would be inventing data that does not exist, and I can't exactly have a `NullString` object (can't extend `String`) to represent non-existent data.

`hasText(String s)` must be able to accept any of this input data and thus must be able to accept `null`.

Comment: I can't understand what do you want. I mean, your parameter of `hasText` is a String - not a null. And you're trying to pass the `null` instead of `String` calling `String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : null;` Try to write `String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : "";`

Comment: @zlakad the String may be null if the data did not exist, the data could come from a variety of sources and I can't exactly create a NullString object to prevent the string from ever being nullable.

Comment: O.K. Why don't you use an `Optional<String> mayBeNull;`?

Comment: FYI, `(s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()) ? false : true` is just longhand for `!(s == null || s.trim().isEmpty())`, or `s != null && !s.trim().isEmpty()`.

Comment: @shmosel Whoops. I had just compressed a larger if-else into that ternary operation and it slipped my mind that I should've just simplified it into a boolean expression. Good catch.

Comment: @zlakad That would require a code change in a lot of places but it is an ok idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is safe (it never throws a null pointer exception), but perhaps Eclipse's analysis is too weak to establish that.  You should consider using a more powerful tool.

The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/)'s [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) can prove your code is safe.  You just need to express the contract of `hasText`:  `hasText` takes a possibly-null argument, and it returns true only if its argument is non-null.

Here is how to express that:

```
@EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="#1", result=true)
static boolean hasText(@Nullable String s) { ... }
```

(For more details, see the [Javadoc for @EnsuresNonNullIf](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/EnsuresNonNullIf.html).)

Here is your full example, which the Nullness Checker verifies without warnings:

```
import java.util.Random;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.EnsuresNonNullIf;

public class Test {

    // validator method
    @EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="#1", result=true)
    static boolean hasText(@Nullable String s) {
        return !(s == null || s.trim().isEmpty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // s could come from anywhere and is null iff the data does not exist
        String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : null;
        if (hasText(s)) {
            // Potential null pointer access: The variable s may be null at this location
            System.out.println(s.length());
            // ... do actual stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the type of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public class Test {

    // validator method
    private static boolean hasText(String s) {
        return s != null && !s.trim().isEmpty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : null;
        if (s != null && hasText(s)) {
            System.out.println(s.length());
            // ... do actual stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you could simplify the `hasText(String)` method to:

```
    // validator method
    private static boolean hasText(String s) {
        return !s.trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

Another alternative would be to just avoid ever producing a `null` value:

```
public class Test {

    // validator method
    private static boolean hasText(String s) {
        return !s.trim().isEmpty();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = (new Random().nextBoolean()) ? "valid" : "";
        if (hasText(s)) {
            System.out.println(s.length());
            // ... do actual stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question for better clarity. Unfortunately I don't see a way to avoid the data being able to be null, and thus `hasText()` must be able to accept null. This validator method is used in many places so it would be somewhat difficult to bring the null check outside of it but either that or ignoring the warning may be my only option...